# Create tooltip with specific content in StencilJS

Tags: typescript, tooltip, stenciljs

I'm really new in StencilJS so I need some help.

I have an array like:

```js
[
  { value: 50.5, color: "#2c8646", tooltip: "Done" },
  { value: 30, color: "#69c0f9", tooltip: "" },
  { value: 10, color: "#e03021", tooltip: "Have data:<span>12</span>" },
];
```

So, I need to return a div for each element. The two properties at first are styles for divs that show as series bars, but tooltip is that, a tooltip that shows the data in that property. If the value of tooltip is void, the tooltip doesn't show, but if it has, the tooltip has to be shown and also supporting html code.

Bar series are done but I need to implement the tooltip. I see that maybe using <slot> to avoid some decisions but not sure how to do it.

I have this:
[image: four-coloured horizontal bar]

And this is how I code the series with a draft for tooltip:

```js
return this.objArray.map((element) => {
  return (
    <div
      class={element.tooltip == "" ? "" : "hoverbar"}
      style={{
        background: element.color.toString(),
        width: element.value.toString() + "%",
      }}
    >
      {element.tooltip != "" ? (
        <div class="tooltip">{element.tooltip}</div>
      ) : (
        ""
      )}
    </div>
  );
});
```

And I need to add this:
[image: bars with one tool tip shown]

As you can see, the tooltip has to be in the middle of its container and support HTML.

Comment: I would caution against using supporting HTML in the tooltip unless you have absolute control over the contents of that `tooltip` field and can very strongly guarantee that it will never contain user generated data. Otherwise, your component/app may be vulnerable to cross-site scripting vulnerabilities.

Comment: Are you asking how to position the tooltip? How to show/hide the tooltip? Or both?